# VS2015 can't find include headers in subdirectory

Tags: c++, include, visual-studio-2015, websocket++

I've been trying to include the WebSocket++ header only library to a project in VS2015. I've added the websocketpp folder to the source directory and included it in the project, so that the hpp files shows up in the header filter. But when trying to compile example code for the library I keep getting the error that it can't open the source files for:

```
#include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls.hpp>
#include <websocketpp/server.hpp>
```

I've been searching around for a solution and tried adding the websocketpp folder to the project include directories and additional include directories, but haven't found a solution to the problem. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Does your Solution Configuration/Solution Platform match the versions that you're updating when you provide the folder you're including?

Comment: ***I've added the websocketpp folder to the source directory*** Does that also contain a websocketpp folder inside of it? I ask because the include path expects to find a websocketpp folder inside one of the folders in your includes. If there is no websocketpp/websocketpp folder you need to add the folder containing websocketpp to your includes.

Comment: You can use " ... " instead of < ... > and use paths relative to the location of the source files.

Comment: @drescherjm the websocketpp didn't contain another websocketpp folder with caused the error. included the source directory instead with fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @dresherjm pointed out the error was that the include path was to the websocketpp folder, but the include path expected the folder containing the websocketpp folder.

To fix the error the include directory needed to be changed to the folder containing the websocketpp folder.